# Floating app on Android (Windowed app)

Tags: android, floating, windowed, moveabletype

Does anyone know how I can create a floating window? (Image below shows what I mean) - [source code](https://github.com/serso/android-calculatorpp)

I've read on various websites that in order to do so an app must be running as a service which should in turn be running as an activity using 'TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT'.

If the above is or isn't true ... I still don't know how to implement the code. Can someone write some code showing how a simple app (click button and do something) can be made into a floating window, Thank You :)

This may also help - [facebook chatheads](http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/)

[image: Floating Window App]

Comment: Does this calculator screen your expecting to show on top of any app?

Comment: Yes, that's correct + it should be resizable and movable

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**These q&a's (linked below) where helpful for achieving what i wanted:**

[Possible to inflate an XML layout in a Service? (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19540098/3470343)

[Creating a system overlay window (always on top)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4482868/3470343)

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to use the great open source Standout library: https://github.com/pingpongboss/StandOut

Comment: The point is that popups are not a standard feature of Android (or most other similar platforms). You need outside help.

Comment: I already know about the StandOut library, But I'd like to know how to do it using my own code. Thanks for the tip though

Comment: @sudoman I had used StandOut before, and it's really good. In the link FD_ posted, you could follow [thread in xda](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1688531) to use it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use WindowManager to inflate a view. Something like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


overlay = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.overlay, null);

final LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
                        LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);


WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
if (overlay.isShown()){
        wm.updateViewLayout(overlay, params);
}
else {

        // add overlay
        wm.addView(overlay, params);
}
```

Whit this you can inflate any view on any application.

Hope it helps you!!

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to check out Tooleap SDK: http://www.tooleap.com