# Floating application on Android screen

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Is there any way to create something like that in this post but in Delphi FireMonkey?: [Floating app on Android (Windowed app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22731445/floating-app-on-android-windowed-app)

I mean an application like 'floating calculator' from screenshot in above link.

Comment: Start by placing a TRectangle on the form. Then add buttons to the TRectangle.

Comment: I thought about sample code of some service or something similar