# Android N picture in picture

Tags: java, android, android-picture-in-picture

I would like to know whether it is possible to implement Pip mode in Android N or below? There is no problem with the Android O version, everything works fine according to the documentation. But some of my users send me videos and screenshots that on Android N implemented peep mode. If anyone has any knowledge in this moment? Maybe there are some links, otherwise I did not find anything ...

Comment: Your can add views to windows, which doesn't belong to your activity. That is how twich pip works.

Comment: @Ufkoku Can you give references if there are examples?

Comment: I think if you use Android Services + Window manager (To add UI), You can do this. But the Pip mode transitions won't be there.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539887/possible-to-inflate-an-xml-layout-in-a-service-android/19540098#19540098

Comment: @Ufkoku Thanks, I will watch

Comment: IIRC, PiP was added to phones/tablets in O. It only existed on Android TV prior to that.

Comment: @CommonsWare I do not agree, it was developed long ago, and was present in Marshmallow, and even earlier. It was just closed, as it had many bugs, you can safely activate it in Nougat, even the standard settings of android studio allow you to do this without errors, just there are many nuances, everything below Oreo will not know how to behave ...

Comment: Well, [Google seems to think that it is only on phones and tablets in Android 8.0 and higher](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0). Nobody should be assuming that some undocumented/unsupported PiP mode will work across all the phones and tablets that were released prior to Android 8.0. Manufacturers did not need to support such a PiP mode and may not have tested what is there.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, that's right, officially it is with android, but it is fairly well supported on android n, it seems to work well.

Comment: "it is fairly well supported on android n, it seems to work well" -- your question indicates otherwise.

Comment: @CommonsWare That's right, thanks to the link that I indicated "Sudhi", I found a solution. Having found as much documentation with this functionality.

Comment: That is not picture-in-picture mode. That is something else. It can be *used* like picture-in-picture mode, albeit with some security issues.

Comment: @CommonsWare I’m not saying that this link solved my problem, I’m saying that blogging to her I found a solution to the pip mode. Although the link option offers a davolno alternative solution, although it is problematic in terms of optimizing for older versions of Android.